# OpenLayers 6 - ES6 project structure

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, openlayers

I'm working on a project using OpenLayers 6 in ES6 with Webpack.
It's my first real ES6 project and I want to make it organized (and a bit modular) but I'm struggling with the use of imports and exports.

Currently my structure is :

```
- all.js
- map/
   - index.js
   - gpx.js
```

The `all.js` file is the "entry point".

**all.js**

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import map from './map/index';
import { vector as GPXvector } from './map/gpx';

map.addLayer(GPXvector);
```

**map/index.js**

```
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import { OSM } from 'ol/source';
import { Tile as TileLayer } from 'ol/layer';

const map = new Map({
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
        center: [1037749, 5135381],
        zoom: 10
    })
});

export { map as default };
```

**map/gpx.js**

```
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style } from 'ol/style';
import { unByKey } from 'ol/Observable';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import GPX from 'ol/format/GPX';
import map from './index.js'; // Is that good ??

const style = {
    // [...] Some style here
};

const source = new VectorSource({
    url: 'test.gpx',
    format: new GPX()
});

var onChange = source.on('change', function() {
    if (source.getState() == 'ready') {
        map.getView().fit(source.getExtent()); // Access to "map" from "index.js" HERE
        unByKey(onChange);
    }
});

const vector = new VectorLayer({
    source: source,
    style: function (feature) {
        return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
});

export { vector, source };
```

I want to access to the `map` instance (initialized in `map/index.js`) from the `map/gpx.js` file (see comment in source code).
But I feel like I am importing `map` from `map/index.js` inside `all.js`, which is importing `map/gpx.js` which himself also imports `map` from `map/index.js`.
It sounds to me like some kind of "loop" imports where it will be a mess to handle the order of imports for example when I'll get more files in my project.

Also if you have any advice for me to start properly with ES6 it's cool !

### EDIT 1

I changed to something else to see if it allows more granularity.

**all.js**

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import map from './ntrak/index';
import MyGPX from './ntrak/gpx';

const gpx = new MyGPX(map, 'test.gpx');
```

**map/gpx.js**

```
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style } from 'ol/style';
import { unByKey } from 'ol/Observable';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import GPX from 'ol/format/GPX';

const style = {
    // [...] Some style here
};

const _onSourceChange = function(map, source) {
    if (source.getState() == 'ready') {
        map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());
        unByKey(_onSourceChange);
    }
}

export default class {
    constructor(map, url, fit = true) {
        this.map = map;
        this.url = url;
        this.fit = fit;
        this.loadGPX();
    }

    loadGPX() {
        this.source = new VectorSource({
            url: this.url,
            format: new GPX()
        });

        if (this.fit) {
            this.source.on('change', () => _onSourceChange(this.map, this.source));
        }

        this.vector = new VectorLayer({
            source: this.source,
            style: function(feature) {
                return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
            }
        });

        this.map.addLayer(this.vector);
    }
};
```

I think it's cool because it allows to get multiple GPX vectors on the same map instance.
But if I want to do more stuff that interacts with my GPX source or vector I will need to pass the instance everytime instead of just importing the GPX file directly.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CircularDependencyPlugin](https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin) for `webpack` to track such circular dependencies.
There is no circular dependency in your example, `import map from './index.js'; // Is that good ??` is ok.

Your es6 code is fine to me, I see one `var` usage (`var onChange = ...`), you should replace that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I edited my question because I also tried by exporting a Class. I would like to know the drawbacks of either one or the other solution.